# Power Query: Apostrophe in Custom Column Name

Tags: powerquery, custom-fields

I have an odd situation that I haven't been able to find an answer to. In Power Query, my custom columns have suddenly developed an apostrophe before the field name.

[[image: (see screenshot)]]

The code line is below, which doesn't include any tick marks and the field is formatted as dates so not sure where this is coming from. I tried deleting the apostrophe manually once the results loaded in Excel, but wasn't successful (delete apostrophe, hit enter, return to cell and it's still there). Any ideas?

```
"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type3", "Renewal_Date", each Date.EndOfMonth([DATE_MATURITY_NEXT]))
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no apostrophe in the field name. You are loading the results into a table on the excel sheet, and that is how it displays left-aligned text in the formula bar.  Try formatting the cell as right-aligned and the display will show "Renewal_Date; with center alignment formatting will show ^Renewal_Date

See prefix section of [excel documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/cell-function-51bd39a5-f338-4dbe-a33f-955d67c2b2cf?NS=EXCEL&Version=16)

> Text value corresponding to the "label prefix" of the cell. Returns single quotation mark (') if the cell contains left-aligned text, double quotation mark (") if the cell contains right-aligned text, caret (^) if the cell contains centered text, backslash () if the cell contains fill-aligned text, and empty text ("") if the cell contains anything else.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. I get what you're saying about the label prefix, but I right-aligned and center-aligned the text and still have that prefix showing up. I'm affecting the load results in Excel because I couldn't find a way to adjust the alignment within Power Query. Maybe I'm not changing the alignment properly though?

Comment: @lat125 did you ever solve this? I have the same issue